# How to properly attach .Jar file into HTML

Tags: java, html, applet

I have a program in Java (NetBeans IDE) that accepts as Dataset a folder named "Data" with .zip files, then makes some major compares for Plagiarism and extracts the results in a .txt file in folder "Results" (there is no GUI in program).I created a .jar file with Clean and Build and if i double click on it, it runs without problems.Also it runs normally in CMD.How can i embed this in HTML?I tried with   without a result.chkSubmission is the main class.I tried almost all public classes in my program.I included the dist folder of Netbeans into my folder of HTML pages .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (there is no GUI in program) .. How can i embed this in HTML?

You can't.  The only Java classes that **can** be embedded in HTML are `java.applet.Applet` and `javax.swing.JApplet`.  Both are GUIs.